# Clarification of the change in vector A

Tags: physics

I understand that a change of the vector **A** can be the result of a rotation and a change in magnitude. (The perpendicular part and the parallel part)

This can be represented by Δ**A** = Δ**A**(perpendicular) + Δ**A**(parallel)

What I am having difficulty understanding is how |Δ**A**(perpendicular)| = *A*Δθ

and how  |Δ**A**(parallel)| = Δ*A* (for small angles of θ).

[This is the image used in the textbook I am using. Would appreciate if the answer could be related to this image. Thank you.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G23Pc.png)

Comment: Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Since for small angle $\Delta \theta$ we have

- $\sin \Delta \theta\approx  \Delta \theta$
- $\cos \Delta \theta \approx 1$

we obtain

$$\|\Delta\vec A_\perp\|=\|\vec A(t+\Delta t)\|\sin \Delta \theta \approx \|\vec A(t+\Delta t)\| \Delta \theta$$

$$\|\Delta\vec A_\parallel\|=\|\vec A(t+\Delta t)\|\cos \Delta \theta -\|\vec A(t)\|\approx \|\vec A(t+\Delta t)\| -\|\vec A(t)\|$$

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity reasons, let $\underline{B}=\Delta\underline{A}$ and $B=|\underline{B}|$ (And so on for the other vectors). Then we have that
$$\underline{B}=\underline{B}_{\bot}+\underline{B}_{\parallel}$$
You can see that $\underline{B}$,$\underline{B}_{\bot}$ and $\underline{B}_{\parallel}$ can be the sides of a right triangle (if you move them a bit). So we have that
$$\sin(\theta)=\frac{B_{\bot}}{B}$$
$$\cos(\theta)=\frac{B_{\parallel}}{B}$$
And if $\theta$ is really small (maybe around some degrees), we have that $\sin(\theta) \approx \theta$ and $\cos(\theta) \approx 1$, so
$$\theta \approx \frac{B_{\bot}}{B}$$
$$1 \approx \frac{B_{\parallel}}{B}$$
And finally
$$B\theta \approx B_{\bot}$$
$$B \approx B_{\parallel}$$
Note that $\theta$ is measured in radians, not degrees.